# Why do I get a strict-aliasing warning when using C-style arrays, but now when using std::array?

Tags: c++, arrays, reinterpret-cast, strict-aliasing, type-punning

When compiling the following code with gcc 4.7 (g++-mp-4.7 (GCC) 4.7.0 built with MacPorts on OS X) I get seemingly contradictory results.

The compiler does not complain when I try to reinterpret and dereference a section of an `std::array` as an `uint32_t` but it does when using a C-style array.

Example code:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {    
    std::array<uint8_t, 6> stdarr;
    *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&stdarr[0]) = 0; // OK

    uint8_t arr[6];
    *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&arr[0]) = 0;
    // ^ error: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Werror=strict-aliasing]
}
```

Compiler command is:

```
$ g++ -o test -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp
```

Why are they treated differently?

Comment: Interestingly, I do not get any errors on gcc 4.7 on ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit.

Comment: @juanchopanza Does it work with `-Wstrict-aliasing=2` ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Not even a warning.

Answer (score 4):

When taking the address of the `std::array`, the expression `arr[0]` is equivalent to the function call `arr.operator[](0)` which returns a reference, rather than the pointer arithmetic expression `(arr + 0)`. Perhaps the compiler does not attempt to "see through" the `operator[]` function call when generating aliasing warnings.